# How to set a child attribute as collection_select value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, collections, simple-form

My form contains the following tag:

```
<%= f.collection_select :employee_id, @employees, :id, :value, :prompt => true  %>
```

Employee looks like this:

```
employee
  - attr1
  - attr2
  - user
     - firstname
     - lastname
```

My question: How to set the `lastname` of an `employee` as the value in the select field? I'm pretty sure it's possible, but I think I have some gaps in the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you do that?

It's possible, with:

```
<%= f.collection_select :employee_id, @employees, :last_name, :text_method, :prompt => true %>
```

Where `:text_method` is method which called on `@employees` members will return text that you'd like to appear in dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You may be asking yourself why I have used `<%= f.select %>` this is FormOptionHelper on the Ruby on Rails Api this is very similar to `collection_select` however with that it returns  and  tags for the collection of values. Whereas `select` creates a series of contained option tags for provided object and method. So in saying this I believe you could have the following:

```
<%= f.select(:employee_id, Employee.all.collect { |emp| [emp.lastname, user.id] }
             .sort{ |a, b| a[0] <=> b[0] }, {:prompt => "Select a Employee"}) %>
```

This selects all employees and sorts them in order of their last name.